# How do I read integers from a text file containing integers and strings in java programming?

Tags: java

I need to read only the integers and sum them from a file.  I do not know how to "skip" the strings or bypass them to only read the integers. So here is my code and the only options I have in the chapter we are on are the `while (!scan.hasNextInt())`.  This is my code and minus the lines that i just added, it works with files that are only integers. The file looks like this:

```
1
2
John
3
4
Black
5
Jason
7
8
```

There is a number or a string on each line.
I do not understand how to use this method.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int number;
        int temp;
        int i;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        double count = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;


        File inputFile = new File("Values.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (file.hasNext())
             {
            if (!file.hasNextInt()) {           //this just added
                String s = file.nextLine();     //added
             }                                  //added
            else {                              //added
                 number = file.nextInt();
            }

            for (i = 2; i <= (number / 2); i++)
            {
                temp = number % i;
                if (temp == 0)
                {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
                }
             }
            if (isPrime) {
                 //System.out.println(number);
                 total = total + number;
                 count = count + 1.0;
             }

         isPrime = true;

         }
         //System.out.println(total);
         //System.out.println(count);
         System.out.println(total / count);
         System.out.println("File is Empty");
         file.close();
     }

 }
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? What are you trying to accomplish and where do you need help?

Comment: I suspect you need a `continue;` after `String s = file.nextLine();` - if that's not the issue, a little more explanation of how your results deviate from your expectations would be **very** helpful.

Comment: Your  Java class can't be compiled. On line `for (i = 2; i <= (number / 2); i++)` you try to access `number`, which might not have been initialized at this point. An IDE like IntelliJ will show you these things. If that's not the problem you encounter, please provide a bit more detail, of what you are trying and if you get an error.

Comment: I suggest you read the next line into a string. Then try to parse that line into integer, skip over if it cant be parsed into integer. It is less complexity when you make judgement after you read it from a file.

Comment: Please don't un-do my edits. They have been made to help make your question more readable.

Comment: so yes to Jan, that is the problem I encounter and Harry, I am trying to figure out how to bypass the lines with strings and continue on. The way the program is now, if it encounters a string i get errors (minus the lines that i just added).

Comment: Thank you to everyone that helped.  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1 Hello 1 World 2 3 Hello 7";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            sc.next();
        } else {
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you....this worked....but what is the difference  between sc.next and sc.nextLine.  If I'm to truly learn I would like to know..  I was thinking nextLine would skip to the next line and continue reading the integers.

Comment: When using `nextLine()` you assume that there are line breaks in the file after each number or word, but that's actually not the case. It's safer to go to the next number/word rather than next line.

Comment: The documentation might give you a clear idea: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Comment: Thanks.  It is much appreciated.